# Increase tooltip character limit

Tags: c#, webforms, tooltip

Is possible to increase the character limit of a tool tip?

I have a particular field where the text that I want to display is too long to be fully displayed. I show only the first few characters and the tooltip show the rest, however is getting hidden.

it is possible to increase the number of characters of the tool tip to display the entire message?

Comment: Which framework are you using? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2010 , C# with web forms .

Comment: From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.tooltiptitle.aspx): `The maximum length of a title is 99 characters. If this property contains a string longer then 99 characters, no title will be displayed.`

Comment: @user2827342, then what tool tip framework are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments it sounds like you're using the built in tool tip framework (i.e. the browser). However, I'd recommend that you leverage a custom tool tip framework. I'd recommend the jQuery UI one.

1. Download the jQuery UI `.js` file [from here](http://jqueryui.com/download/). **NOTE:** you can customize the download, so just check the `Tool Tip` library.
2. Include that `.js` file in your page.
3. Execute the following JavaScript. You could do this with a `<script>` tag at the top of the page - or in another `.js` file that you may have for initialization.

---

```
$( document ).tooltip();
```

---

If you don't already use jQuery, [then download it here](http://jquery.com).